# Easy way to get TRIAC dimming onto a typical LED strip?

Tags: led, circuit-design, home-automation

I’m trying to build a light fixture which uses a 24V 30W LED strip that can be connected through mains power to a typical Lutron TRIAC wall dimmer. I can’t seem to find any type of driver product which can connect the strip to the dimmer, and which is small enough to fit inside the 3.5x3.5x3 inch space in the fixture. Surely a solution for this must exist? Am I thinking about this the right way?

My thought is that a constant current driver (I’ve seen some that have TRIAC dimming) with a specially designed led circuit would do the job better, but I’m trying to use off the shelf led strips because of their form factor. As I understand it, led strips must be fed by a constant voltage driver. Is there a simple solution to get TRIAC dimming?

Comment: You really can't dim LEDs with triacs.

Comment: Digikey has lots of LED drivers that support triac dimming.

Answer (score 0):

My local hardware store has 'transformer' 'bricks' that accept the phase controlled waveform from a triac dimmer. Basically these are a constant current DC supply that senses the mains being chopped and modulates the output DC. The downside of these is that they don't dim down to 0% - they might get to 20% then drop out. This is similar to the 'dimmable' led bulbs.

Compare this to the 'smart' wifi bulbs that will dim smoothly down to 0%

The bricks I mention are for 12V, I'd expect there are some for 24V. Then there's the size issue.

I'd suspect the cost of a retrofit would be less performant and more expensive than just using modern 'smart' controllers.